# Как сделать показ изображения в нужном боке при наведении курсора на маленькое изображение?

Tags: css3, html, css, javascript

Есть страница товара с главной картинкой, под ней еще 4 дополнительных изображений этого товара.

```
http://gyazo.com/26352bead9807866c8abb56b5c3b366e.png - пример
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора на маленькое изображение, вместо большого изображения показывалось то маленькое изображение на которое наведен курсор, а при уводе курсора с маленькой картинки все возвращалось в исходный вид.

**РЕАЛИЗОВАЛ ТАК:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
            var tabContainers = $('div#slider-img-products > div.s_block');
            tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

            $('div#img-nav ul a').hover(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('div#img-nav ul a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');
                return false;
            }).filter(':first').hover();
        });

        $(function () {
          var lastId,
              topMenu = $(".nav"),
              topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()-20,

              menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),

              scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
                var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
                if (item.length) { return item; }
              });



        });
    </script>
```

HTML код:

Большие изображения :

```
<div id="slider-img-products">

<div class="s_block" id="slide-1">картинка большая</div>
<div class="s_block" id="slide-2">картинка большая</div>
<div class="s_block" id="slide-3">картинка большая</div>

</div>
```

Маленькие изображения :

```
<div id="img-nav">
    <ul>
    <li class="slide-1"><a href="#slide-1">картинка</a></li>
 <li class="slide-2"><a href="#slide-2">картинка</a></li>
 <li class="slide-3"><a href="#slide-3">картинка</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть множество вариантов...

Во первых разделить изображение на части.
У вас сейчас в одной картике показывается и большой вариант и 4 разных превьюшки.
Сделать что то вида

```
_______________________________________
|                                     |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|             main image              |
|                                     |
|                                     |
|_____________________________________|
|         |       |         |         |
|   1     |   2   |   3     |    4    |
|_________|_______|_________|_________|
```

Далее есть много путей:

1. При наведении на блоки 1,2,3,4 менять изображение  main image. Допустим у вас будет сразу 4 div элемента с 1 изображением в каждом. эти 4 div находятся друг под другом и виден только один из них, при наведении на разные блоки 1,2,3,4 видимый div сменяется (т.е. одному присваивается hiiden, у другого убирается это свойство).
2. На ебее например идет аякс подгрузка изображения при наведении на уменьшенное изображение. и меняется атрибут src.
3. Чтобы было совсем быстро - можно слепить main image в виде

   ---

   ```
   |                 |                 |                  |               |
   |     Большая     |     Большая     |     Большая      |     Большая   |    
   |    картинка     |    картинка     |    картинка      |    картинка   |    
   |        1        |        2        |        3         |       4       |  
   |  изображения    |  изображения    |  изображения     |  изображения  |            
   |_________________|_________________|__________________|_______________|
   ```

показывать только часть этой картинки, допустим общая ширина 400пикселей, тогда ширина показываемого участка 100 пикселей (overflow : hidden)
При наведении на блок 1,2,3,4 менять показываемую часть изображения.
Минус в том, что такие картинки придется обрабатывать руками, так что рекомендую остановиться на первых вариантах.

Comment: Друзья спасибо за подробную помощь, записал ваши варианты! попробую сделать, но реализовал по другому смотреть в обновленном вопросе...

Answer (score 1):

Один из многочисленных возможных способов:
При наведении (`mouseover`) на маленькую картинку копировать ее через jquery `.clone()`. Скрывать главную картинку (`.hide()`). Вставлять (`.append()`) копию рядом с главной картинкой. При необходимости расширить ее до нужных размеров. 
При уводе курсора с картинки (`mouseout`) удалять (`.remove()`) вставленную картинку-копию. Показывать главную картинку (`.show()`).

Comment: Если с jQuery совсем туго, придется учить. И иметь представление о том, что такое DOM не помешает.